# ошибка при запуске docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, docker-compose

Установил контейнер python в docker
Настроил его в pycharm.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настроил интерпретатор
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу установить библиотеки в pycharm
попробовал установить через консоль:

```
pip install <имя библиотеки>
```

Библиотека установилась успешно, но ее не видно. Что я делаю не так?

Сам контейнер ставил через kitematik, так же хотел собрать контейр сам без kitematik, но выходит ошибка.

Dockerfile

```
 FROM python:3.6
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

requirements.txt

```
pandas
lxml
cssselect
XlsxWriter
```

docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '2'
 services:
   db:
     image: postgres
   web:
     build: .
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
       - .:/code
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
       - db
```

выполняю команду

```
docker-compose run web  startproject composeexample
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
   PS D:\docker python> docker-compose run web  startproject composeexample
    ERROR: Cannot create container for service web: D: drive is not shared. Please share it in Docker for Windows Settings
```

убрал строку стала выходить ошибка

```
Removing intermediate container 1794eefd67fa
Successfully built 145154c97b94
WARNING: Image for service web was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-co
mpose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"startp
roject\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Comment: а что вы хотите получить? какое желаемое поведение?

Comment: поставить библиотеку я пользовался этим руководством [https://hub.docker.com/_/python/](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)

Comment: это ссылка не на руководство, а на образ с python.

Comment: я ставлю через kitematik, но том нет готовых решении которые мне нужны.

Comment: я создал свой контейнер, создал Dockerfile, requirements.txt, docker-compose.yml запускаю не идет пишет ошибку 'PS D:\docker python> docker-compose run web  startproject composeexample
ERROR: Cannot create container for service web: D: drive is not shared. Please share it in Docker for Windows Settin'

Comment: добавьте Dockerfile, requirements.txt, docker-compose.yml  в вопрос.

Comment: @mikhail-vaysman добавил в вопрос

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: Добавил код в сообщение

Comment: Можно попробовать питоновскую библиотеку руками добавить, то есть физически файл.

Comment: вы сделали то, что рекомендуется в ошибке?

Comment: command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 убрал

Comment: у вас есть файл `startproject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение не знаю на сколько, оно идеально.

Dockerfile, requirements.txt, docker-compose.yml есть выше в вопросе.

выполняю команду:

```
docker-compose run web composeexample
```

выходит ошибка:

Removing intermediate container b44086c37a95
Successfully built 0fc23d053871
WARNING: Image for service web was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"composeexample\": executable file not found in $PATH"

выполняю команду:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Заработало.

Comment: откуда вы взяли вот эту `docker-compose run web startproject composeexample` команду?

Comment: убрал startproject

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ отсюда

Comment: вы просто не дочитали до конца. эта команда для создания проекта. а для запуска команда в самом конце.

Comment: ключ `--build` обычно не нужен.

Comment: пересоздал 3 раза все работает как я хотел)
теперь нужно собрать cmake в doker для clion